# Java versioning and terminology, 1.6 vs 6.0 OpenJDK vs Sun

Tags: java, versioning, terminology

I'm having problems understanding Java versioning. I'm seeing lots of versions like 1.4.2, 1.5 and 1.6, but I also stumble upon 5.0 and 6.0. I don't understand this versioning or the progression.

I'm pretty new to Java, and I've read a bit about [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) vs Sun, and I think I understand it. Are these versions the difference between OpenJDK and Sun? For example, OpenJDK's latest is 1.6 and Sun's is 6.0?

All these versions are pretty confusing to someone new to Java.

Comment: Basically java went from 1.0 to 1.1, to 1.2 etc. and then Sun decided to change the naming convention to 5, 6 instead of 1.5, 1.6, but it never really stuck, even the version reported by `java -version` doesn't follow the new convention.

Comment: Relevant https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8061493

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The versioning is simply a mess:

- Java 1.0 and 1.1 were normal
- Then came Java 1.2, but you were supposed to call it "Java 2, JDK 1.2"
- This continued until 1.4 (There were also minor releases like 1.4.2)
- The next version was then supposedly "Java 5.0", but there was still "1.5" all over the place in the file names and URLs.
- Starting with Java 6, they've dropped the minor version and mostly (but not completely, see output of `java -version`) eliminated the traces of the old versioning scheme, but people have gotten used to it and continue to use it colloquially.
- Starting with Java 9 or 10, the 1.X notation also disappeared from the output of `java -version` (which caused some code that depended on parsing it to break), and people have pretty much stopped using it. We now have Java 15, Java 16, Java 17, etc.

Note also that when this question was asked, Sun JDK and OpenJDK were separate codebases (whith a large overlap), and Sun JDK was the official reference implementation.

In the more than 10 years since then, Java was sold to Oracle, OpenJDK became the official Java reference implementation, and Oracle stopped maintaining the Oracle JDK as a separate codebase. Instead, they just provide OpenJDK builds and provide commercial long term support for them with bugfixes and security patches. But you can also get builds for free from AdoptOpenJDK (which recently rebranded as ["Adoptium"](https://adoptium.net/)), they just aren't supported as long.

Comment: ya on snow leopard `java -version` gives me "1.6.0_17"
which is really what has caused all of my confusion because i read all about 6.0

Comment: The minor versions aren't clear either.  Sometimes you see build x or update y.  I guess build == update?

Comment: What is JDK 17 from OpenJDK then?

Comment: @IliaSidorenko note that this answer was over 10 years old. I've added an entry for the current situation.

Comment: I hated java already, now I have one more reason.

Comment: @SirajAlam it doesn't seem very healthy to me to go around and collect outdated grudges against a programming language.

Comment: Just chill Mike, I’m just kidding.

Answer (score 21):

This is explained (cough) in [Java SE Naming and Versions](http://java.sun.com/javase/namechange.html):

> The current release is Java Platform,
> Standard Edition 6 (Java SE 6). The
> previous release was Java 2 Platform,
> Standard Edition 5.0 (J2SE 5.0).
>
> Sun Microsystems simplified the
> platform name in 2006 to better
> reflect the level of maturity,
> stability, scalability, and security
> built into the Java platform. Sun
> dropped the "2" from the name and
> deleted the "dot number" (the number
> following the period). Any updates to
> Java platforms will simply be noted as
> updates rather than adding a "dot
> number" at the end of the platform
> name.
>
> Due to significant popularity within
> the Java developer community, the
> development kit has reverted back to
> the name "JDK" from "Java 2 SDK" (or
> "J2SDK"). The runtime environment has
> reverted back to "JRE" from "J2RE."
> (Note that "JDK" stands for "J2SE
> Development Kit" in version 5.0.)
>
> For more information on platform names
> and version numbers, see the following
> pages:
>
> - [Java SE 6 Platform Name and Version Numbers](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/version-6.html)
> - [J2SE Version 1.5.0 or 5.0?](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/version-5.0.html)
> - [J2SE SDK/JRE Version String Naming Convention](http://java.sun.com/j2se/versioning_naming.html)

And quoting [Java SE 6 Platform Name and Version Numbers](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/version-6.html):

> At this release, the platform name has changed from J2SE<sup>TM</sup> to Java<sup>TM</sup> SE. The official name is Java<sup>TM</sup> Platform, Standard Edition 6.
>
> Both version numbers (1.6.0 and 6) are used to identify this release of the Java Platform. Version 6 is the **product version**, while 1.6.0 is the **developer version**. The number 6 is used to reflect the evolving level of maturity, stability, scalability and security of Java SE.

And [J2SE Version 1.5.0 or 5.0?](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/version-5.0.html):

> Both version numbers "1.5.0" and "5.0" are used to identify this release of the Java 2 Platform Standard Edition. Version "5.0" is the **product version**, while "1.5.0" is the **developer version**. The number "5.0" is used to better reflect the level of maturity, stability, scalability and security of the J2SE.
>
> The number "5.0" was arrived at by dropping the leading "1." from "1.5.0". Where you might have expected to see 1.5.0, it is now 5.0 (and where it was 1.5, it is now 5).

So, to summarize, the whole naming is a mess but this is [finally over](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kgh/archive/2005/06/goodbye_j2se_he_1.html) and the current **platform name** is Java<sup>TM</sup> Platform, Standard Edition 6 (abbrev. Java<sup>TM</sup> SE 6). Two **Products are delivered under the platform**: the JDK<sup>TM</sup> 6 and the JRE<sup>TM</sup> 6.

[OpenJDK 6](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/) is an open-source implementation of the Java SE 6 Platform, it's different from Sun's JDK.

Comment: And I would argue that we can retroactively now clearly and unambiguously refer to Java 1, Java 2, Java 3, Java 4 and Java 5, being java.version 1.0.x/1.1.x, 1.2.x, 1.3.x, 1.4.x, 1.5.0, respectively.

Comment: Yes, they removed this insane 2 in J2SE so *this* insanity is finally over.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt Since Solaris was more messy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29 ,the question is what oracle will introduce ;-)

Comment: It should be noted that the OpenJDK version shipped by Red Hat, Fedora, et al has passed the Java TCK certifying them as valid/correct runtimes, unlike most (all?) other open source JDK implementations.

Answer (score 7):

- Java 1.5.x is the same as Java 5.x
- Java 1.6.x is the same as Java 6.x

Basically throw away the 1. part of the version number.

Comment: and so there's no difference between openjdk and sun ??  as far as versioning?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there never was anything called Java 4. The move to "full" version numbers started with 5.

Comment: @brad, Glen is just answering the version number question. Openjdk and Sun's JVM are two separate JVM implementations.

Comment: do different jvm implementations have to stick to specific versions according to some spec?

Comment: There is a difference: version 6 is the product version, while 1.6.0 is the developer version.

Answer (score 2):

[Both 1.6 and 6 are used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0_.28September_30.2C_2004.29) to refer to the same version (and similarly for 1.5 and 5).

Comment: thanks for that link, i was searching around, but couldn't find exactly that!

Answer (score 2):

[Guide to java versions](https://dzone.com/articles/a-guide-to-java-versions-and-features)  is the best blog for any new person to understand java versioning
Since 2019, Java releases new version every 6 months, i.e. March and September. 
It's October 2021, and Java 17 is already released. Here is the link to download [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/)
Couple of noteworthy points

1. you can use always use the latest version of java, it will execute the code written using previous versions
2. previously JRE and JDK were separately distributed, now there is a trend to only distribute JDK
3. There are two distributions: OpenJDK (free) and OracleJDK (paid)

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the single digit numbers are usually used in conjunction with [Java SE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition) 5 and [Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) 6.

The 1.5 and 1.6 versions are what the Java compiler says using `java -version` and sometimes '*the minor release*' is used as a version string, like SunOS 5.8 was called Solaris 8 as a product name.