# How do I determine the JDK version based on the javac -version output?

Tags: java, version, versioning

Most people (and the Oracle website) seem to refer to the JDK version as a single digit, like "Java SE Development Kit 7."

However, the output of `javac -version` is of the format: `javac 1.6.0_24`

I suspect, but would like some verification that the second digit, 6 in this case, refers to the JDK version.  Is this correct, or is there another way to determine the single-digit JDK version?

Comment: short answer: You are correct. See here for more information: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411288/java-versioning-and-terminology-1-6-vs-6-0-openjdk-vs-sun

Comment: Feel free to vote to close this question as a duplicate [2411288](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2411288/403455)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second digit is almost the correct answer.

```
For 1.7, "Java 7"
For 1.6, "Java 6"
For 1.5, "Java 5"
For 1.2 through 1.4, "Java 2" or alternatively (if being more specific) "Java (second digit)"
```

Java 1.1 and 1.0 was simply marketed as "Java".  Not enough people were using 1.0 to trigger a re-branding in the more capable 1.1.