# what is the difference between java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386 and java-7-openjdk-i386

Tags: jvm, java

when i install netbeans it gives me the option to select the java environment, i have 3 options, the oracle java and these two (**java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386** and **java-7-openjdk-i386**). what is the difference between these two?The os if ubuntu.

Comment: I think 1.7 is the JDK and 7 is the JRE according to http://openjdk.java.net/install/

Comment: @RNJ I don't think that one is the jre. I am on Ubuntu and I have the same case with JDK6. One of them is a symbolic link. Also, in case of JRE it is named so. However, I can speak only for Ubuntu. Also the link that you have added does not differentiate with `jre` and `jdk` based on the version format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two `OpenJDK` are same. However OpenJDK is slightly different from Oracle JDK. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060671/difference-between-oracle-jdk-and-openjdk) for more clarification.

The reason why you are getting two options for OpenJDK is PROBABLY that you have two copies of OpenJDK installed (or two different references to the same directory on your system.)

For further investigation, try to `ls -lh /usr/lib/jvm`. The **/usr/lib/jvm** is usually the directory where Java gets installed. Check if one of them is a symbolic link. Also, check in netbeans the location of the two JDK and see if in fact you have two versions or references of Java on the system.

For example, here is the output of `ls -lh` on my system:

```
ls -lh
total 24K
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    26 Sep 10 13:41 default-java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    18 Mar 13  2012 java-1.5.0-gcj -> java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6
drwxr-xr-x 7 root  root  4.0K Aug 22  2012 java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    19 Jun 26  2012 java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386 -> java-6-openjdk-i386
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root  4.0K Feb 15 10:52 java-6-openjdk-common
drwxr-xr-x 7 root  root  4.0K Feb 15 10:52 java-6-openjdk-i386
drwxr-xr-x 8 ankit ankit 4.0K Jun  6  2012 java-6-sun
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root  4.0K Aug 22  2012 java-7-openjdk-i386
drwxr-xr-x 8 root  root  4.0K Feb 20 10:40 java-7-oracle
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    12 Mar 13  2012 java-gcj -> java-gcj-4.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  root    18 Apr 16  2012 java-gcj-4.6 -> java-1.5.0-gcj-4.6
```

As you can see `java-1.6.0-openjdk-i386` is just a symbolic link/reference to another directory named `java-6-openjdk-i386`

Comment: yes i know what is the difference between oracle jdk and openjdk, what i don't understand is why i get two options, and not sure which to select.

Comment: hmm the one with the 1.7... is a symlink to the other :  java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386 -> java-7-openjdk-i386. like @Ankit write, still don't get why it is done like that

Comment: @Nikola It is result of java versioning mess. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411288/java-versioning-and-terminology-1-6-vs-6-0-openjdk-vs-sun

Comment: this means that both are practically the same :), that was my question :)

Answer (score 3):

You installed it twice

From openjdk, following instructions from [here](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

From Stackoverflow, following instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263556/installing-java-7-on-ubuntu)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Would recommend the second one and remvong the first one by typing

`sudo apt-get remove openjdk-7-jdk`.