# Java JDK and JRE versions

Tags: java

I have a simple theory question.

In the documentations Gradle I read
"Gradle requires a Java JDK or JRE to be installed, version 6 or higher".

If I check to my computer which version of java I have it shows,
"java version "1.7.0_79"",
does that mean that I have java version 7?

thanks and best regards!

Comment: [something worth reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2411377/681929)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's right, you have Java in version 7 on your path.