# Explanation on JDK terminology

Tags: java, java-8

This might sound silly but since I am new to `Java` I am confused. So far in my learnings I have come across these terms

- Java 8 - which I believe is the language specification
- JDK 8 - an implementation of the above specification (e.g. [This](https://github.com/treasure-data/digdag/#prerequirements) repo uses JDK 8)
- JDK 1.8 - Older version of Java? (e.g. [Netflix conductor](https://github.com/Netflix/conductor#other-requirements) uses JDK 1.8+)

Are these terms used interchangeably? Googling JDK 1.8 leads me to JDK 8. If that is correct, why the dual representation to cause confusion? If not where do I find JDK 1.8?

Comment: JDK 1.8 is JDK 8. Since there has been JDK 1.5, JDk 1.7 etc, some people just refer to is as JDK 8 and drop the 1 before it

Comment: This has been happening [for quite a while now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411288/java-versioning-and-terminology-1-6-vs-6-0-openjdk-vs-sun).  It's not new to java 8.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you.